# jQuery animate using a variable doesn't work in OSX Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, jquery-animate

I have a collapse/expand function that works on everything (**Chrome/Firefox/IE/Mobile Safari**) but is not working in OSX Safari 8.

I've narrowed it down the to the issue stemming from Safari not recognizing my "`maxheight`" variable while all of the other browsers do. If I change the variable to a number it works fine. These `expand/collapse` triggers work on content modules with varying max-heights so I need it to be a variable.

Anyone have any experience with Safari causing this issue?

Here is the JS:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.expansion-trigger', function(e) {
    var el = jQuery(this).parent().prev('.expansion-holder');
    var btn = jQuery(this);
    var ex = '.expansion';
    var exp = '.expansion-trigger';
    var hide = btn.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    var hd = 'hide';
    var sh = 'show';
    var ele = jQuery(this).parent().prev().prev();
    var maxheight = ele.css('right');
    var gpa = btn.parent().parent();
    e.preventDefault();

    if (btn.hasClass('plus')) {
        hide.parent().next(ex).find(exp).removeClass(hd).addClass(sh);
        el.animate({
            'max-height': 3000
        }, 1000);
        gpa.find('.blur').slideToggle();
    } else if (jQuery('html').hasClass('touch')) {
        hide.parent().prev(ex).find(exp).removeClass(hd).addClass(sh);
        ele.removeAttr('style');
        var marg = ele.offset().top - 60;
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: marg
        }, 1300);
    } else {
        hide.parent().prev(ex).find(exp).removeClass(hd).addClass(sh);
        ele.animate({
            'max-height': maxheight
        }, 800);
        gpa.find('.blur').delay(400).slideToggle();
    }

});
```

Associated HTML:

```
<section class="synopsis">
    <?php if( $synopsis = get_field('show_synopsis') ) { ?>
        <h2 class="content__heading u-mb0">Synopsis</h2>
        <div class="synopsis-holder expansion-holder">
            <?php echo $synopsis; ?>
            <p class="blur"></p>
        </div>
        <p class="expansion">
            <a href="#" class="plus show expansion-trigger">Read more <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </a>
        </p>
        <p class="expansion">
            <a href="#" class="minus hide expansion-trigger">Read less <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </a>
        </p>
    <?php } ?>
</section>
```

This probably isn't the best solution, but I'm using the `right` properties in my various holders to reset the `max-height` values when the modules collapse back down. For example:

```
.synopsis-holder {
    max-height: 17rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 17rem;
}
```

Comment: Can you post associated HTML so we can try to see what `ele.css('right')` returns?

Comment: Added associated markup. Let me know if you need to look at the dev site for a live example.

Comment: Safari is recognizing the variable on each click of the .expansion-trigger' but the behavior is different as you noted. Let me dig a bit more and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I scrapped using the value of the `right` property and used data-attributes like `data-height="17rem"` in the markup to store and grab the value.